# Not able to access the Viewbag items in view in MVC using Razor(CSHTML)?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm getting the value from db and assigning values to Viewbag and passing values from controller to view.

**But when i access the items of viewbag/viewdata in view  to hide and unhide,it is giving null reference exception.Viewbag/Viewdata is loosing it's data in view after returning view from controller.Because of which i'm not able iterate through the foreach loop of viewbag/viewdata**

I'm designing data driven controls in the view.Based on the data from the db i want to hide and unhide controls in MVC View???

Please find the code which i'm using: I'm not able to access the viewbag items in my view. If i'm doing wrong suggest me other ways.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     objGenController.CheckTenantControl();
     var result = GetTenantData();
     return View(result);
}


public IEnumerable<TenantModel> GetTenantData()
{
     return (from t in db.Tenant.AsEnumerable()
             join c in db.Country.AsEnumerable() on t.CountryID equals c.CountryID
             join s in db.State.AsEnumerable() on t.StateID equals s.StateID
             join ct in db.City.AsEnumerable() on t.CityID equals ct.CityID
             orderby t.Name
             select new TenantModel()
             {
                  TenantID = t.TenantID,
                  Name = t.Name,
                  Address1 = t.Address1,
                  Address2 = t.Address2,
                  Address3 = t.Address3,
                  CountryID = t.CountryID,
                  StateID = t.StateID,
                  CityID = t.CityID,
                  CountryModel = c,
                  StateModel = s,
                  CityModel = ct,
             });
}

public void CheckTenantControl()
{
     var result = GetTenantControlData();
     List<string> items = new List<string>();
     foreach (var item in result)
     {
          items.Add(item.tc.ControlID.ToString());
     }
     ViewBag.TenantControl = items;
}

public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetTenantControlData()
{
     var result = (from tc in dbEntity.TenantControls.AsEnumerable()
                   where tc.TenantID == 1
                   select new { tc });

     return result;
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Master.TenantModel>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Tenant</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 15px;">
   <tr>
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl)
      {
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            @if (@item.TenantID== 1)
            {
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TenantID);
            }
            else{}
          </th>    
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            @if (@item.Name == 2)
            {
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            }
            else{}
          </th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            @if (@item.Address1 == 3)
            {
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)
            }
            else{}
         </th>
      //Like this i want to hide and unhide
      }
   </tr>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TenantID)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address3)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryModel.Name)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateModel.Name)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityModel.Name)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pin)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TenantID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TenantID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TenantID })
            </td>
        </tr>
   }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is objGenController? Why are you calling that instead of calling CheckTenantControl directly? Alternately, try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewBag.TenantControl = objGenController.CheckTenantControl();
     var result = GetTenantData();
     return View(result);
}

public List<string> CheckTenantControl()
{
     var result = GetTenantControlData();
     List<string> items = new List<string>();
     foreach (var item in result)
     {
          items.Add(item.tc.ControlID.ToString());
     }
     return items;
}
```

Comment: @admanb-Thanks, it worked for me with your suggestion.Now i'm able to control the controls on the view based on the data from db.

Answer (score 0):

your items list should be like below in your controller action:

```
 var items=new List<TenantModel>();
```

In your View

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl)
{
    <th style="text-align: center;">
        if (@item.TenantID== 1)
        {
            @Html.DisplayName(@item.TenantID);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    </th>
}
```

once you added `@` for `foreach` then you do not need `@` for `if`

Comment: @Verkion: I'm getting NullRefernceException wa unhandled by used code,Inner Exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. For foreach loop:@Foreach( var item in Viewbag.TenantControl)it is not going inside the loop.When i see viewbag data it is null why?

Comment: If i debug and see it is getting only Viewbag.Title data which is defined at the top of view(Viewbag.Title).Do i need to define anything at the top of the view in order to access Viewbag.TenantControl.

Comment: @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl) is giving Null reference exception. Anything i need to define in view for Viewbag.TenantControl in-order to access it in view

Comment: @janina-After changing items list in controller i'm getting error for the line: items.Add(item.tc.ControlID);                       Error:The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ALCMS.Web.Models.Master_or_Configuration.TenantModel>.Add(ALCMS.Web.Models.Master_or_Configuration.TenantModel)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @janina-i didn't get what you are telling.i'm already using viewbag

Comment: I observe that after returning an view from controller both Viewbag/Viewdata is loosing it's data. It is null.Why is it So???But if i check the model data it is there!!!

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl)
{
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TenantID)
        </td>
        .......
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @Ashley: I'm getting NullRefernceException wa unhandled by used code,Inner Exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. For foreach loop:@Foreach( var item in Viewbag.TenantControl)it is not going inside the loop.When i see viewbag data it is null why?

Comment: @Intellect:I'm getting NullRefernceException wa unhandled by used code,Inner Exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. For foreach loop:@Foreach( var item in Viewbag.TenantControl)it is not going inside the loop.When i see viewbag data it is null why?

Comment: @Intellect - Control Code is correct but i'm not able to access Viewbag.TenantControl in the foreach loop(@foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl) is giving Null reference exception.What i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @Intellect: I observe that after returning an view from controller both Viewbag/Viewdata is loosing it's data. It is null.Why is it So??? But if i check the model data it is there!!!

Comment: @Vishal did u place the model in your view.

Comment: @VishalIPatil viewbag/viewdata is used to send the data from controller to view, but not view to controller.